# Passing collection dictionary data from C# to macro

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary, vba

I want to passing the collection data dictionary from C# code into excel macros.
The problem that i am facing now is an error during passing dictionary into macros.

Here is a simple example of macro code that exists in excel module that I use:

```
Public Sub dictionaryTest1(dataku As Variant)

Dim I As Integer
For Each v In dataku.Keys
    MsgBox "Name: " & v & " Age: " & dataku.Item(v)
Next
End Sub
```

i
And below is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsMacro
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
    {
        oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, oApp, oRunArgs);
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dataku = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"cat", 2},
            {"dog", 1},
            {"llama", 3},
            {"iguana", 5}
        };

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Excel.ApplicationClass oExcel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        oExcel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
        Excel._Workbook oBook = null;


        //path to excel file at bin folder
        string executableLocation =   Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string xslLocation = Path.Combine(executableLocation, "File.xls");

        oBook = oBooks.Open(xslLocation, oMissing, oMissing,
            oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
            oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

        //Run macros with passing the dictionary data "dataku".
        RunMacro(oExcel, new Object[] { "dictionaryTest1", dataku });
        // Quit Excel and clean up.
        oBook.Close(false, oMissing, oMissing);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook);
        oBook = null;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks);
        oBooks = null;
        oExcel.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
        oExcel = null;
        GC.Collect();   //Garbage collection.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more specific about the error you get. Anyway, I think that your problem is the fact that you are passing your macro the wrong type of object. I.e. you are creating a `Dictionary<string, int>` which is not known by VBA.

You didn't specify which is the type accepted by your dictionaryTest1 macro, but I suppose it is a Dictionary from Microsoft Scripting Runtime. If this is the case, you should create this kind of object in C#, too. This means that yu have to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime to the references of your .NET project and then create the dictionary that will be passed to the macro in this way:

```
        Scripting.Dictionary dataku = new Scripting.DictionaryClass();
        dataku.Add("cat", 2);
        dataku.Add("dog", 1);
        dataku.Add("llama", 3);
        dataku.Add("iguana", 5);
```

Comment: Hi Francesco,  I get message error at excel macro during running the c# script. "Run-time error '424': Object required". any idea how to create and pass the object dictionary data into it ?  if i used your way, i get some invalid arguments due to cannot convert from 'string' to 'ref object'

Comment: That's exactly what you get when the type is wrong. I tried to copy your macro in an excel file and your code in a .NET project and that's the error I got. Then I replaced the creation and initialization of the dictionary and everything wnet fine. Where do you get the invalid argument error?

Comment: I add reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime version 1.0.
within create this dictionary.                                        
Scripting.Dictionary dataku = new Scripting.DictionaryClass();
            dataku.Add("cat", 2);
            dataku.Add("dog", 1);
            dataku.Add("llama", 3);
            dataku.Add("iguana", 5);                             
I got message " Scripting.IDictionary.Add(ref object, ref object) has some invalid arguments."       
another message is related " cannot convert from variable 'string'/'int' to ref 'object'.

Comment: Then you coud try to replace `dataku.Add("cat", 2);` (and all the similar lines) with this kind of code: `object k = "cat";
            object v = 2;
            dataku.Add(ref k, ref v);`